# SAX Parse exception while parsing google calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, gdata

I am using the GDATA API for parsing google calendar. The Calendar is embedded in the website:

```
http://regreformtracker.aba.com/p/dodd-frank-calendar.html
```

I got the the calendar URL from the iframe src used in the above mentioned website which  is :

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?showTitle=0&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=regreform%40aba.com&color=%23182C57&src=7vccf8rlid30a0v4m1004atiqg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=3rpabc5qjf34l49ho337qh9m04%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23691426&ctz=America%2FNew_York
```

I am using the below mentioned snippet:

```
 URL feedURL = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?showTitle=0&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=regreform%40aba.com&color=%23182C57&src=7vccf8rlid30a0v4m1004atiqg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=3rpabc5qjf34l49ho337qh9m04%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23691426&ctz=America%2FNew_York");
 CalendarService service = new CalendarService("TestCalendarFeed");
 CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedURL , CalendarEventFeed.class);
```

I get SAXParseException and below is the stack trace for the same:

```
[Fatal Error] strict.dtd:81:5: The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
Oct 13, 2014 2:09:22 PM com.google.gdata.util.LogUtils logException
WARNING: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd; lineNumber: 81; columnNumber: 5; The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
Message: The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.parse(ParserAdapter.java:430)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.readFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at sample.calendar.TestCalendarFeed.printAllEvents(TestCalendarFeed.java:116)
    at sample.calendar.TestCalendarFeed.main(TestCalendarFeed.java:472)
The server had a problem handling your request.
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd; lineNumber: 81; columnNumber: 5; The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.readFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at sample.calendar.TestCalendarFeed.printAllEvents(TestCalendarFeed.java:116)
    at sample.calendar.TestCalendarFeed.main(TestCalendarFeed.java:472)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd; lineNumber: 81; columnNumber: 5; The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.parse(ParserAdapter.java:430)
    ... 9 more
```

I am not sure what the error is, could you please check and let me know where i am going wrong?

I tried using other calendars , like my private calendar to check if it is the problem with the calendar URL, but even then i am getting the same issue.

I also tried using CalendarFeed class instead of CalendarEventFeed, still i am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your feed url does not point to GData content. https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?showTitle=0&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=regreform%40aba.com&color=%23182C57&src=7vccf8rlid30a0v4m1004atiqg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=3rpabc5qjf34l49ho337qh9m04%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23691426&ctz=America%2FNew_York is an html web page rather than an xml feed. In any case, GData is deprecated and should not be used (will be shut down in November this year). Try taking a look into reading this calendar through API v3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to access the data from the calendar embedded in th web site mentioned above. So how do i do it if the link i mentioned above represents a html page? How do i know what is the correct URL to be used for this calendar? Is there any other way to get the event date and event information for teh above mentioned calendar?

Comment: There are three different calendars referenced in this link: regreform@aba.com, 7vccf8rlid30a0v4m1004atiqg@group.calendar.google.com, 3rpabc5qjf34l49ho337qh9m04%40group.calendar.google.com I propose you look into the documentation of events list operation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list But before you do it, read the getting started guide here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/get_started